# "Rescue" command in R?

Tags: r, web-scraping, internal-server-error, rvest

I have this code:

```
library(rvest)
url_list <- c("https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/100", 
               "https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/200", 
               "https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/300")

mine <- function(url){
  url_content  <- html(url)
  url_mainnode <- html_node(url_content, "*")
  url_mainnode_text <- html_text(url_mainnode)
  url_mainnode_text <- gsub("\n", "", url_mainnode_text) # clean up the text
  url_mainnode_text
}

messages <- lapply(url_list, mine)
```

However, as i make the list longer I tend to run into a

```
Error in html.response(r, encoding = encoding) : 
  server error: (500) Internal Server Error
```

I know in Ruby I can use `rescue` to keep iterating through a list, even though some attempts at applying a function fails. Is there something similar in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use `try()`. For more info, see [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Exceptions-Debugging.html). Here's an implementation:

```
library(rvest)
url_list <- c("https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/100", 
               "https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/200", 
               "https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/300")

mine <- function(url){
  try(url_content  <- html(url))
  url_mainnode <- html_node(url_content, "*")
  url_mainnode_text <- html_text(url_mainnode)
  url_mainnode_text <- gsub("\n", "", url_mainnode_text) # clean up the text
  url_mainnode_text
}

messages <- lapply(url_list, mine)
```

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged, and I would say especially so when they are just mentions of a well known facility. If you want to earn your rep, then paste a complete worked example. I find the practice of answering most of your questions with short interval and no effort at searching to be bordering abusive practice.

Comment: I agree with your first point - I added an example. I disagree with your second point (answering own questions). See here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: I think asking questions to which you either know the answer and have not searched and it appears to be a fairly trivial answer crosses the line of posting dummy questions and immediately posting answers.